# Why does my Blazor app process not release memory?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I created a new project using the Blazor Server template. I modified the following bit in startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddServerSideBlazor(o =>
{
    o.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); // 10 seconds
    o.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); // 10 seconds
    o.MaxBufferedUnacknowledgedRenderBatches = 3; // down from 10
    o.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 1; // down from 100
});
```

I also added a button that triggers default garbage collection: `<button @onclick="@(() => { GC.Collect(); Console.WriteLine("Collect"); })">`.

I started the app and attached to the process via VS 2019. Next, I clicked around the pages, refreshed a few times, and watched my memory grow to about 125MB. Finally, about 10-15 seconds later (after the `DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod`), I triggered GC with the button a few times, but this barely impacted memory consumption (reduced it by about 4 MB).

[image: Memory Usage]

Even after closing the app, the process is still at 121MB several minutes later. I would have thought that configuring the `CircuitOptions` would have allowed more resources to free.

**Why does my app build up memory between page navigations and refreshes** (even without component interactions)**?** The counter page resets which tells me the previous state is lost forever, but GC doesn't seem to free anything.

Follow up: how can I get my memory back after a client refreshes? I have a much more complex app that takes thrice the resources and it doesn't seem like this could sustain more than a dozen users at one time.

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler to see what objects are resident in memory?  In particular, you should see if any of your own classes are lingering around.

Comment: I have, but **this is the default app**: I haven't added anything new except the startup configuration changes and the test button.

Comment: It is possible that the GC hasn't tried very hard to free as much memory as possible because it realises there isn't a need for it yet. Generally, in GC'd languages, the link between the total sizes of containers (like the ones you changed) and the actual memory being consumed is not as direct as in non-GC languages.

Comment: @bennyboy1973 I'm not concerned with the amount of memory used; I want to know why it isn't freed. I have another app that uses around 30MB per user to start: after enough time, it can reach upwards of a GB. If there is a solution to this simple project, I can, in theory, apply it to a larger one (there, I **am** concerned with the amount of memory).

Comment: Have you tried connecting as multiple users to see what happens?

Comment: @benny I don't have users in the strict sense; it's the default app and I didn't opt-in to any auth schemes. Do you mean multiple sessions or browsers?

Comment: Full confession, this is kind of out of my wheelhouse, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can weigh in.  But it seems to me that if 100MB is the overhead (for maintaining services, etc.) then that's no problem.  So you need to find out what happens when you apply some load to the site.  MS Devs seems to think pretty highly of Blazor's memory usage: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-server-in-net-core-3-0-scenarios-and-performance/

Comment: @benny understood, I've read that article a few times. I'm just trying to understand how memory management works in the simplest case possible so that I can determine if our larger project (which has consumed upwards of 10GB after running for a while with half a dozen users) has a memory leak or is just poorly configured/optimized.

Comment: I'm REALLY hoping someone has an answer for this because I have been experiencing the same issues with my blazor server app hosted on heroku.  The memory climbs and climbs and never comes down.  Using a memory profiler shows that the RenderTree.ArrayBuilder keeps growing and growing and all i'm doing is just calling "StateHasChanged".  I recently started using Blazor and I love it but this is just a deal breaker.

Comment: A bit of an update on this. There is a very easy way to reproduce the issue i'm seeing. Create a new blazor server app (3.1 or 5.0). Run it and click on the Counter tab. Start clicking on the "Click me" button for a full minute. Watch the diagnostics memory profiler and watch the process memory tick up a 1 or 2 mb. If you continue to click the memory will slowly start to grow. Interestingly enough if I spin up a blazor wasm app and run the same experiment, memory stays steady.

Comment: @minimalist_zero, Blazor WASM runs client-side, so you would see it boost the memory consumption of your browser instead. We see this on Blazor Server because it is a stateful server application.

Comment: @ConnorLow ah i see thx for that

Comment: Hi, have the same issue right now. Did you found a solution? After every page refresh on my server side Blazor app the memory grow up.

Comment: Just a lot of optimization.
We ended up changing when we were rendering a lot of our invisible content (modals, dropdowns, etc.) to only show up on the DOM when we needed it. We also replaced a lot of cascading state (i.e. with `[CascadingParameter]` in children) with injected scoped services that fired events.